# how to save data in HDFS with spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I want to using Spark Streaming to retrieve data from Kafka. Now, I want to save my data in a remote HDFS. I know that I have to use the function saveAsText. However, I don't know precisely how to specify the path.

Is that correct if I write this:

```
myDStream.foreachRDD(frm->{
    frm.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://ip_addr:9000//home/hadoop/datanode/myNewFolder");
});
```

where `ip_addr` is the ip address of my hdfs remote server. 
    `/home/hadoop/datanode/` is the DataNode HDFS directory created when I installed hadoop (I don't know if I have to specify this directory). And,
    `myNewFolder` is the folder where I want to save my data.

Thanks in advance.

Yassir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The path has to be a directory in HDFS.

For example, if you want to save the files inside a folder named `myNewFolder` under the root `/` path in HDFS.

The path to use would be `hdfs://namenode_ip:port/myNewFolder/`

On execution of the spark job this directory `myNewFolder` will be created.

The datanode data directory which is given for the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml`  is used to store the blocks of the files you store in HDFS, should not be referenced as HDFS directory path.

Comment: ok thanks, it is very clear. In your case, what would be the value of the 'port' ?

Comment: You have used 9000 as the port, the same has to be used. This is the RPC port defined in `core-site.xml` for property `fs.defaultFS`.

Comment: I did why you told me to do but I don't see any new file created and spark does not return any error..

Comment: Strange! Is the folder created? Also please check you have access to the remote hdfs

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: my new folder and files don't appear in linux commands. But if I connect through a browser to master:50070 I can see them

Comment: These are HDFS files, you should use HDFS specific commands. Refer [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html)